# VS2010 C++ - problem casing based class pointer to derived class pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, polymorphism, smart-pointers, derived-class

Using VS2010 and C++, I am using a supplier library to interface to their USB industrial camera.

The library has an base abstract class for data stream sinks called `GrabberSinkType`, and one of derived classes from that is `MediaStreamSink` which deals with writing streams to video files. One of the methods supported by `MediaStreamSink` (not a virtual function of the base class) is `getFilename()` which simply returns the name of the file being written to.

The main `Grabber` class which handles streaming has a method `getSinkTypePtr()`, which returns a pointer to the sink in current use, defined as `smart_ptr<GrabberSinkType> getSinkTypePtr() const;`.

What I need to do is check if is a MediaStreamSink, and if so, get the filename. And I cannot get it to compile. Having checked if it is a media stream type, all I am doing is

```
CString    SinkPath = dynamic_cast<tMediaStreamSinkPtr>(m_cGrabber.getSinkTypePtr())->getFilename().c_str();
```

(`tMediaStreamSinkPtr` is typedef'd as`smart_ptr<MediaStreamSink>`). This results in error 2680:

"error C2680: 'DShowLib::tMediaStreamSinkPtr' : invalid target type for dynamic_cast
target type must be a pointer or reference to a defined class"

I have tried every possible combination of dynamic casts, static casts, old style casts I can think of, and whilst the error changes, I cannot get it to compile.

I clearly don't know what I'm doing here, how do I get a pointer to the dervied class and successfully call its `getFilename()` method?

Comment: template instantiations of two types are not related to each other even if the types are related. Whatever `smart_ptr` is needs to provide a specialised dynamic cast like [`std::shared_ptr` does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

Comment: And in fact that library provides [`static_smart_ptr_cast`](https://www.theimagingsource.com/support/documentation/ic-imaging-control-cpp/meth_descDShowLib_static_smart_ptr_cast.htm)

Comment: Excellent, it even has a relevant example, thank you both very much.